# Java, JSF Web application doesn't load resourses from JAR library

Tags: java, jsf

I am trying to use adminfaces template, primefaces theme in JSF project. I've set up libraries in netbeans project, but it doesn't load resourses from it. For instance 404 page on the image.You can see it actually loaded configured 404 page, but resourses aren't loaded, including style, and labels from properties file etc... What am i doing wrong? Also it is deployed on wildfly 12.[image: 404 page]

Comment: Please provide the relevant code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Well i really don't have any, i just loaded libraries, template, etc... The defined page is inside jar library, adminfaces-template. This is the output from that default page from template. And i stopped at this momment because i need that template working. I now see exception in the wildfly log:  `WARNING [com.github.adminfaces.template.config.AdminConfig] (default task-1) Could not load user defined admin template properties.: java.lang.NullPointerException`. So again it goes to that, that resourses aren't loaded.

Comment: @cvetan: that is nonsense.. Seriously. The page you have above is at least made up of sourcecode. The 'adm' you try to load a label from is declared/defined/loaded **somewhere**. The fact that it is defined as a 404 page is configured in a file. So if you cannot produce any code, please don't be angry if this question is closed because of 'No [mcve] provided'...

Comment: OK. It is declared in jar library. Should i post content of files from library? If yes, which ones? Could anything from my project files be usefull?

Comment: I've found solution with the author of the adminfaces theme in the github. Sorry if i made any confustion, the solution was in the FacesServlet url pattern. My NB project was set up to "faces/*", and template path was in the root.